# Initial Firebase Login Auth not recognized by security rules

Tags: javascript, firebase

I have a bit of an odd issue. My users need to logout and then login to ‘trigger’ the Firebase security roles correctly upon first sign up. Here is the flow:
User submits details to a cloud function
Cloud function uses admin Auth to create user and return response.
On client side, when response is received the user is logged in using the credentials provided, and then receives a notification that they need to verify their email.
After they click the verification link, it refreshes client side until it recognizes the email is verified.
At that point it makes a call to my real-time database, and this is where permission is denied. However, if they logout and log back in, security rules recognize everything correctly. Here are my rules:

```
  "rules": {
        "sendRequests":{
          ".read": false,
            "$requests":{
              ".write": "auth!=null && data.exists()",
            }
        },
        "Notify":{
          ".read":false,
          "$userCardID":{
            ".write": "auth!=null"
          }
        },
        "$users":{
          ".read": "auth != null && auth.token.email_verified===true",
            ".write": "auth.uid === $users",
            ".indexOn":["Name"],
                    "Roster":{
            "$cardID":{
             ".validate": "root.child(auth.uid+'-admin').child('Collection').child(newData.child('ID').val()).exists()" 
            }              
          },
          "Completed":{
            "$cardID":{
             ".validate": "root.child(auth.uid+'-admin').child('Collection').child(newData.child('ID').val()).exists()" 
            }              
          },
          "ToDos":{
            "$cardID":{
             ".validate": "root.child(auth.uid+'-admin').child('Collection').child(newData.child('ID').val()).exists()" 
            }              
          }
        }
      }
}
```

Curious if this is by design or if I’m missing a step here. I have checked that the user is being created and data is being added to the database under the correct user ID BEFORE the email verification.

EDIT: I should also mention that after receiving the response from the cloud function the user is logged in programmatically using the stored email and password, they don't actually 'click' a login button. Not sure if that changes anything.

EDIT: Here is the client-side code:

```
//This function is trigger when the user clicks on the 'Submit' button on the client form. 
//searchString(username),eml(email),and pwd(password) or all grabbed from the 'input' values of the client form.
//It generates a random 'code' and then submits the data to a firestore doc, this triggers the cloud function to pull the data.

const usersRef = db2.ref();
function createRequest() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let prefix = "Req"
    let code = prefix;
    for (let it = 0; it < 2; it++) {
      let number = Math.floor(Math.random() * (9999 - 1000) + 1000);
      code = code.concat(number)
      if (it === 1) {
        return resolve(code);
      }
    }
  })
}
createRequest().then((code) => {
  dataStore.collection('NewUserRequests').doc(code).set({
    displayName: searchString,
    email: eml,
    password: pwd,
    ReqID: code
  });
  //Then begin listening for the response ('true' or 'error message'). On 'true' it logs in the user.
  dataStore.collection('NewUserResponses').doc(code).onSnapshot((doc) => {
    log.debug("New user response is: " + doc.data());
    //I have verified on the console this is being received correctly.
    if (doc.data().Response === true) {
      login_user(eml, pwd);
    } else {
      alertNative(doc.data().Response);
    }
  })
});
//the login function for firebase
function login_user(email, pwd) {
  firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pwd).then(function(user) {
    newLogin = true;
  }, function(error) {
    log.error("User login error: " + errorMessage);
  });
}
//After login, the firebase auth state change gets triggered:
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
if (user) {
    log.info("User Auth Detected")
    //I use the photoURL field to determine if a user is 'new'. I know its not elegant but it works.
    let newNameCheck = firebase.auth().currentUser.photoURL
    if (newNameCheck !== null) {
      if (newNameCheck.indexOf("http://www.example.com/12345678/newUser.png") !== (-1)) {
        createNewUser = true;
        firebase.auth().currentUser.sendEmailVerification().then(function() {
          log.info('Email Verification sent.') // Email sent.
        }).catch(function(error) {
          log.error('There was an issue sending the verification email: ' + error)
        });
      }
    }
    if (user.emailVerified === false) {
      log.warn('This user is not verified!')
      let checkEmail = setInterval(function() {
        firebase.auth().currentUser.reload().then(check => {
            if (firebase.auth().currentUser.emailVerified === true) {
              //FINISH LOGGING IN/BUILDING NEW USER
              clearInterval(checkEmail);
              finishLoginSequence();
            }
           })
        }, 2000)
        } else {
        log.warn('This user is verified!')
        finishLoginSequence()
        }
   }
   //ALL code up to this point triggers normally as expected. When it hits finishLogin Sequence is when permission is denied.
   function finishLoginSequence(){
    log.warn(firebase.auth().currentUser.emailVerified);
    firebase.auth().currentUser.updateProfile({
              photoURL: ""
            }).then(function() {
              log.info('Succesfully update new user profile.')
            }).catch(function(error) {
              log.error('There was an error updating the new user profile: '+error)
            });
    //THIS is approved, and I see the in the console that the profile has been updated.
    currentUser = user.uid;
    log.warn(firebase.auth().currentUser.emailVerified);
    usersRef.child(currentUser+'-admin').child('Collection').once('value',function(snapshot){
        let collection  = snapshot.val()
      fullCollect.push(collection)
      //It never gets here as permission is denied!!
    })
   }
});
```

LOG FILE OUTPUT

```
[2021-05-13 19:06:00] Sess7967g4164k [info]  User Auth Detected Caller: lobby.js:1590:11)
[2021-05-13 19:06:00] Sess7967g4164k [warn]  This user is not verified! Caller: lobby.js:1637:13)
[2021-05-13 19:06:00] Sess7967g4164k [info]  Email Verification sent. Caller: lobby.js:1597:17
[2021-05-13 19:06:08] Sess7967g4164k [info]  Email verification has been received. Caller: lobby.js:1642:19
[2021-05-13 19:06:11] Sess7967g4164k [warn]  true Caller: lobby.js:1676:15)
[2021-05-13 19:06:11] Sess7967g4164k [info]  New user detected. Begin building new user account. Caller: lobby.js:1698:17)
[2021-05-13 19:06:11] Sess7967g4164k [warn]  true Caller: lobby.js:1734:17)
[2021-05-13 19:06:11] Sess7967g4164k [error] UnhandledRejection Error: Permission denied
    at https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.3.2/firebase.js:1:394396 Caller: catchErrors.js:35:15)
[2021-05-13 19:06:12] Sess7967g4164k [info]  Succesfully update new user profile. Caller: lobby.js:1702:19
```

RULES FOR THE FIDDLE TEST DB:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "UserID999":{
      ".read": "auth != null && auth.token.email_verified===true",
        ".write": "false"
    },
    "UserID888":{
      ".read": "auth != null",
        ".write": "false"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you're doing the right things. It's more likely we can help however if you share the actual [minimum client-side code with which any of us can reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), instead of describing. In that code *prove* that the conditions your rules check for are being met, so that the user exists and their email is verified, for example by logging those values and including that output in your question too.

Comment: hi frank, I will go through and grab the necessary code and add it to my question. Do you need to see the admin side code (it's pretty much just copy pasted from the documentation on creating a new user by an admin).

Comment: Not as long as your client-side code proves that these conditions are being met `auth != null && auth.token.email_verified===true` before it accesses the database. At that point though, it is unclear how this relates to Cloud Functions so it might be good to update your tags.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen added in the client-side code. Let me know if anything needs clarification. Thank you so much.

Comment: It seems to be related to the email verification. I removed the requirement to be verified from my security rules and it loaded okay.

Comment: So it fails in `finishLoginSequence`? Can you log `firebase.auth().currentUser.emailVerified` inside that function?

Comment: hi Frank, I got this message in console: "[2021-05-13 14:35:49] Sess1035m3748r [error] There was an issue sending the verification email: Error: We have blocked all requests from this device due to unusual activity. Try again later." I just followed steps I found online by deleting the last few users I created and now it all seems to be working. I didn't receive the error until the 4th or 5th failed attempt however.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen still happening. I attached the log files. And added the log lines so you can see where I am calling them in the code.

Comment: Hmmm.... I don't see what's going wrong there. Are you sure you're trying to load from the database whose rules you show, and that those are the complete rules?

Comment: Hi Frank, I know its the right rules and database because I can get it to work by removing the email verification check in the rules. I posted the full rules incase something else is triggering it but I don't think so? Is it possible (forgive the lack of technical) that the auth token that the rules are reading does not refresh until it detects a new login?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I made a public database in firebase and a public fiddle that recreates the problem. I'll add the security rules as an edit. If you have a test email service you can try the different paths, one that needs verification and one that doesn't. https://jsfiddle.net/sychordCoder/8cqsyptu/2/

Comment: The `auth` variable in the rules comes directly from the ID token that is passed with the request. So once the client has the correct value for `emailVerified`, so do the rules for `email_verified`. Or at least that's how it's supposed to work. :-/

Comment: Well, I have it now set to sign out and then immediately sign the user back in (all in the background) so my login sequence works "as intended" but I thought it was odd it didn't recognize the verify.